# Insert a default signature with a picture into an email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write the VBA code that will insert the default Outlook signature into an email that has been generated in Excel. There's a few people that might use the Excel template, so I need the VBA code to pick up the default signature of the user that's creating the email.

I've found various helpful things online, however I can't get it to work. I'm new to VBA so still learning.

The code below works for the email I need - expect the signature as I've removed all that code as I couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub EmailCreator()

ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim blRunning As Boolean

    blRunning = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
        blRunning = False
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    strBody = "This is my message in HTML format"

    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olMail
        .Subject = "abc"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .HTMLBody = strBody
        .Display
    End With

    If Not blRunning Then olApp.Quit

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code that *doesn't work* to insert the signature? It's hard to tell *why* it doesn't work if we can't see it!

Comment: Hi Samuel, that's the thing...I don't know the code to get VBA to lookup a default signature.  Do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try any of the answers already here on SO?

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question then, as "*The code below works for the email I need - **expect the signature as I've removed all that code as I couldn't get it to work**.*" contradicts your above comment. - On a side note, I recall trying something with vba and outlook default signatures but never resolved it (I no longer develop that application), sorry!

Comment: Thanks Samuel. I'll make the edits as you've suggested.

Comment: @BigBen - I have tried a few of them, however I can't get Outlook to display the default signature at all.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and how it didn't work, so that we know what to suggest or not?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Outlook will insert the default signature when you call `Display` **if** the message body has not been modified yet.

Secondly, once you call `Display` (and the message body gets populated with the signature), you will need to merge the two HTML strings - not just set the `HTMLBody` property (which would wipe out the signature), not concatenate the two HTML strings (which cannot produce a valid  HTML document), but **merge**. The easiest would be to look for the position of the "`<body`" substring, scroll to the next "`>`" character (to take care of the body tag with attributes), then insert your HTML after that "`>`" character.